# Brake Pads - Wagner ThermalQuiet 537

Tags: honda, brakes, accord

New pads on Honda Accord 2004. The 537 pads, like many others, have a 'wear indicator' on one pad per set.

Question -- does the wear indicator pad go on the inside of the rotor or outside?

If it is correctly positioned on the inside where the piston will push, will the raised pins interfere with the piston's action? I know the piston will slide and turn during operation. The piston surface is not smooth, it has a cross channel to accept the tool used to push the piston back in when installing new pads.
Thanks, Tom

The 'comments' box is limiting how much I can say so I'll try here ----- in response to the answers -- I installed the pads(rear) so a photo I can't send. I placed the pad with wear indicator clip on the inside, like the pads I removed. There were no raised pins on the old pads. That's why I'm confused. Wagner offers no help in explaining their purpose. It just seems counter intuitive given the piston surface has the cross channel design.Is the piston going to rotate as the pad wears? If not this is a none issue I guess. But I know the piston has to be turned to get it back into the caliper the next time new pads are installed. If turning/rotating is required to go back in, it makes sense that it turns as it's pushed out further with pad wear. The simple solution -- place the smooth surface pad inside -- Wear clip pad outside. Any reason not to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The wear indicator should go on the inside of the rotor, towards the top. Realize, the wear indicator will be on opposite sides on the two pads they are located on. It shouldn't interfere at all.

Not knowing exactly how you're doing your work, it's always a good idea to only work on one side of the car at a time. This will allow you to see how the other side is put together and therefore you can duplicate it to the working side if you lose your way in how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the rear... there should be no raised pins that are anywhere near the caliper piston.

Those pins are not the wear indicators, or any part of it.  The piston should locate flush with the surface of the pad backing plate.

If the pins are in contact with the piston, they need to be located into the "cross channel".  The are there to prevent the piston from rotating during apply.

Can you take and upload a picture of the back of the pad?  I'm not completely sure what you are referring to.  The wear indicators are usually metal clips on the outer edge of the pad.

Comment: You are always welcome.  LET'S GITTERDONE....   If you could upload a cellphone picture, there's a lot of seriously edumicated people volunrteers that will steer you the right way...